# Creating Two SQLite Tables in Same Class

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have only ever used SQLite with one table.  I now need a Database with two tables.  Here is how I do it now:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TABLE_CAT = "cats";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_CAT = "cat";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cats.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
            + TABLE_CAT + "( " + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CAT
            + " text not null)";

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAT);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

In addition to the table called "cats", I want one called "items" with the same rows.  What changed need to be made on this?

Note:  This app is still in testing, so I don't need to worry about updating DB versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why cant you just make two queries, like

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ONE = "create table "
            + TABLE_CAT1 + "( " + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CAT1
            + " text not null)";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_TWO = "create table "
            + TABLE_CAT2 + "( " + COLUMN_ID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_CAT2
            + " text not null)";
```

and in your onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_ONE );
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_TWO );
}
```